# React passing all values as props instead of selected value

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am trying to make a popup modal for editing user's activity and I tried to pass the current Activity ID using props. However, it passed all value of Activity ID that user currently has. For example, if user has two activities from activityList which have ID 1 and 2, and when I click 2, the props passed would be both 1 and 2. However, I only want 2 to be passed.

```
{activityList.map((val, key) => {
                                return(
                                    <div key = {key}>
                                    
                                    <Row>
                                        <Col>
                                            {val.project_activity_title}
                                        </Col>
                                        <Col>
                                            {val.project_activity_information}
                                        </Col>
                                        <Col><Button variant="link" className = "btn btn-link mr-3"
                                             onClick=
                                             { () => setEdActivity(true)
                                            }
                                             >Edit</Button>
                                             <EditActivity
                                                activityID={val.project_activity_id} //pass activity ID here
                                                itemID={projectCode}
                                                show={edActivity}
                                                
                                                onHide={() => setEdActivity(false)}
                                            />
              
                                        </Col>
                                  

                                    </Row>
                                    
                                    </div>
                                )
})}
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Need more code here or some working example to answer accurately but this is my best guess. 

I think you are using `EditActivity` component is a modal window. 
- Which has hide/show mechanism with `edActivity` attribute/state for all instances in the loop. 
- That results in visibility of multiple modals. 
- Hence you're seeing multiple IDs.

Comment: @MehulThakkar yes you're correct on that. How do I fix that?

Comment: Added an answer with the updated code.

Comment: Updated answer again, Missed clearing the flag earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In continuation of my comment earlier,

> Need more code here or some working example to answer accurately but
> this is my best guess.
> I think you are using EditActivity component is a modal window.
>
> - Which has hide/show mechanism with edActivity attribute/state for all instances in the loop.
> - That results in visibility of multiple modals.
> - Hence you're seeing multiple IDs.

Here's a possible solution which can help here. You need to set individual id for which you want to show the modal, for `show/hide` flag you can just compare the value of `project_activity_id` with `edActivity` state.

```js
{activityList.map((val, key) => (
    <div key = {key}>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          {val.project_activity_title}
        </Col>
        <Col>
          {val.project_activity_information}
        </Col>
        <Col><Button variant="link" className = "btn btn-link mr-3"
          onClick={() => setEdActivity(val.project_activity_id)} // Updated setter
        >Edit</Button>
        <EditActivity
          activityID={val.project_activity_id} //pass activity ID here
          itemID={projectCode}
          show={edActivity === val.project_activity_id} // Updated Comparison
          onHide={() => setEdActivity(undefined)} // Updated setter
        />
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
))}
```